# For loop ES6 no longer Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I swear to God this was working, I know it was because my test was passing for a while...now it does not.  See the error screen shot below.

```
describe('', () => {

    let newBoard;

    beforeEach(() => {
        newBoard = new board();
    });

    it('', () => {
        for(let row in newBoard){
            for(let column in row){
                newBoard[row][column].should.equal("");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**board.js**

```
module.exports = function(){
    return  [["", "", ""],
             ["", "", ""],
             ["", "", ""]];
};
```

[image]

Comment: This could never have worked as expected... The second loop should be `for (let column in newBoard[row])`. (or use a for-of loop).

Comment: @LeeTaylor it says in the screenshot: `newBoard: Array[3]`

Comment: Code doesn't magically stop working, God or no God.

Comment: sorry that newBoard I forgot to show.  Let me update.

Comment: @WTF can you verify that `newBoard` is an array with a length of 3?

Comment: @RobW: not exactly as expected, but `for (var x in "0") console.log(x)` *does* yield `"0"` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the comment by @RobW should the problem: `for (let column in newBoard[row]).`

I wanted to add a suggestion: since you are using ES6 you might want to use the [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```
it('', () => {
    for(let row of newBoard){
        for(let cell of row){
            cell.should.equal("");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few housekeeping items first. You have a for-in loop, not a for loop. A for-in loop is a frequent source of error for folks learning JavaScript because it seems like it does what you want, but its not for iterating over arrays. Its mean to iterate over properties of objects.

The new ES6 loop you are looking for is called a [for-of loop](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/for-of/). It's job is to iterate over items in an array. In your example, try changing your code to use a for-of loop.

```
it('', () => {
    for(let row of newBoard){
        for(let column of row){
            column.should.equal("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it should be `for(let cell of row){ cell.should.equal(""); }`

Comment: Yup, just fixed it. Added the answer too fast without proofing it.

Answer (score -1):

In your inner loop you're asking it to create a variable `column` for each item an object that is a number. The `for in` construct is giving you the index of each item in the `newBoard` array.

The inner loops needs to access the array at the index given for `newBoard` so that your code becomes `for(let column in newBoard[row])`